# Why isn't my SASS watch command working?

Tags: sass, osx-yosemite

Attempting on a Mac with the latest version of Yosemite

I'm using the latest version of sass to refactor my site.  I'm setting up watch command via the command line.  my directory setup has a scss folder with the main css stylesheet cloned as .scss. and no css folder.

When I attempt the `sass --watch scss:css` command while in the main project directory folder, I've been told that, if there isn't one present, a css folder should be generated and a cloned .css file should be created along with a map file.  Command line tells me `>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.` however, changes are not being recorded.

I've tried updating my gems and uninstalling/ reinstalling sass, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Sass issues for anything relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this - the css folder doesn't get autogenerated. You need to generate it yourself. From there on, you should be good to go.

So if you are in the main project folder with subfolders called `scss` and `css` and you have, for example, a `main.scss` file in the `scss` directory, you can run the command exactly as you specified and everything should work as specified.